# How to hold queue execution until get response from web service API in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am going to build lazy loading functionality which has dynamic size records in database, so i am doing this in following manner

1. Initially i fetch say 20 records ,
2. Then i process one,two, or any number of records based on user's clicks (I am not holding user to wait for finish some service call or pending task, so user can do anything with the list like scroll or click etc.)

**Now to maintain consistency i am fetching few records first and then process users record, here i am doing so because the records which i processed are removed from the actual list of records, so here the records at Database and app side are not fixed list.**

I am doing right now with following ways :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // Here i fetch first 20 records and then show in UITableView
   // After user see the list he can click on any button to process that records
 // And i am trying to queue that service call and maintain consistency in records

}
-(void)processOneRecord {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.developer.serialqueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        // To get further records service call

        [self getMoreRecordsCompletionBlock:^{
            [self ProcessOneRecordServiceCall];
        }];
    });
}
```

Here i am creating a method processOneRecord which calls every time user clicks on button on cell

**In processOneRecord method i create completion block for first service call, so second service call definitely run after first service all response. But now when user click on button on another cell i want to wait that first service call until second service call response return to application.**

Comment: are you want perform api call in serial way ?

Comment: Yes, i want to perform api calls in serial way, and thats why i create serial queue.

Comment: you want call second api after you get first api response ? wail i give you answer.

Comment: Yes i want that, and that i achieved using completion block for first service call. But i also want that at second time when first service call is made it also wait for second. I mean i want like looping in waiting queue where both the calls wait for each others for their completion.

Comment: Your attempt to use GCD won't work because you're dealing with asynchronous tasks. If you want to add asynchronous tasks to a serial queue, you should consider using `NSOperationQueue` rather than GCD, because you can write an asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass and not complete the operation until the asynchronous request is complete. See [Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response guys.

I have achieved desired functionality with help of **Rob's** answer, I have created one function in which i write one NSBlockOperation which later i added to NSOperaiotnQueue. And every time when this function calls i cheated whether previously added operation is finished, if yes then add another operation else it will wait previous operation until its completion.

In below code snippet below variable are global to my current UIViewController and also they are initialised in my UIViewController's ViewDidLoad and other respective methods.

```
Bool             isRecordProcessed, isLoadMoreCallFinihsed;
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;

-(void)callTwoAPIServiceCalls {

    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        // To get further records first

        [self getMoreRecordsCompletionBlock:^{
            [self ProcessOneRecordServiceCall];
        }];
    }];

    if (operationQueue.operations.count == 0 && isRecordProcessed && isLoadMoreCallFinihsed) {
        [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    }
    else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(callTwoServiceCalls:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }

}
```